# Bus along Alaska Highway between Whitehorse and Alaska

Tags: canada, buses, alaska, yukon

I'm looking at ways of getting to the [Tachä̀l Dhǟl visitor centre](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/yt/kluane/visit/2/a.aspx#Tachal%20Dhal) at [Kluane National Park](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/yt/kluane/index.aspx), 224 km from [Whitehorse](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Whitehorse) and 253 km from the [Beaver Creek border crossing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcan_-_Beaver_Creek_Border_Crossing).  I've found buses [between Whitehorse and Dawson City](http://www.huskybus.ca/) along the [Klondike Highway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klondike_Highway), buses [between Fairbanks and Tok](http://www.alaskadirectbusline.com/) along the [Alaska Highway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alaska_Highway), and buses [between Dawson City and Tok](http://www.gonorth-alaska.com/index.php?id=357) along the [Top of the World highway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_of_the_World_Highway).  Is there any bus company that operates buses between Whitehorse and Tok along the Alaska Highway?  Presumably if they do, I could contact them to be dropped off (and, 2 weeks later, picked up) at Tachä̀l Dhǟl and/or another location along the same road.

([GoNorth](http://www.gonorth-alaska.com/index.php?id=357) says there *isn't*, but as they sell tickets Whitehorse – Dawson City – Tok the long way it wouldn't be in their commercial interest to link to a company that *does* run such buses, so I don't take their word for it.)

Comment: @pnuts I went on a road trip once with students from The Netherlands, Czech Republic, Brazil, and India, in the spectacular Lofoten area of Norway.  We all agreed it was nice to stop and take photos of reindeer, but the Indian student also wanted to stop whenever we passed along a meadow with some some domestic sheep in in.  The rest of us thought that wasn't terribly special...

Comment: @gerrit: Interesting, since India is [the world's fourth largest producer of sheep meat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb_and_mutton#Sheep_meat_production).  Maybe they just didn't have many in his/her part of the country?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alaska Direct has had summer service between Tok and Whitehorse in years past (connecting with their Anchorage and Fairbanks routes).  You might try emailing them and ask if they will do so next year.

They are the only company that has ever done that route, so you will be limited to hitchiking if they have discontinued it permanently.

Comment: Limited to hitch-hiking... or renting a car.

Answer (score 5):

Alaska Direct and [Alaska Shuttle / Yukon Trails](http://www.alaskashuttle.com/fairbanks.htm) seem to both list the route as a private transfer "charter only" for $500/person, you may want to contact them for more details.

Comment: For that money one might possibly get there by taxi...

Comment: Basically, I guess.